# Draw animation android

Tags: android, animation, ondraw

I really need help.

How can I draw such animation like the one shown in the image?
The ring should be transformed into a solid circle.

[image]

Comment: Of course, you can. There are different ways to do that. My favourite ones: **1** - By using several images in sequence (easiest). **2** - By drawing (lightest): simply use `canvas.drawCircle()` in a loop (the circle ray is decreased in the loop and/or the pen width is increased).

Comment: Ok, I understood. I need a second method. Light circle should have a background color layout on which located the current view. How can I determine the color?

Comment: Unclear... can you rephrase your last comment?

Comment: Well, I'll try to do it. By default, the canvas has a transparent background so if on canvas to draw a ring inside will background color layout on which is drawn a ring. Accordingly, if we draw a solid circle and a light inside the circle, its color need be the same as the background color layout. Otherwise, it will not have the effect I want to achieve. Appropriately, which I have to use a method to determine the color of the external layout, without specifying the colors manually

Comment: use `Canvas#drawCircle` the `Paint` object style should be set to `STROKE` (not `FILL` that is set by default) all what you need is to decrease the radius and increase the stroke's width for each animation frame

Comment: pskink, this does not work. The circle will disappear if the radius reduced to zero and increase stroke width

Comment: what does not work? did you call `paint.setColor` ?

Comment: code in onDraw method
http://prntscr.com/95l3y8

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/4j7AUneh

Comment: Thank you for your example. But that's not it. It must be Colta. After animation turn in a circle. Moreovercircle should appear as in the picture in question. In the example reduces the size of the circle.

Comment: colta? what colta? hey i wrote those lines in 5 minutes, so change the initial radius / stroke width to meet your requirements

Answer (score -1):

I see you comment, you don't need to know the color of background, just draw a ring with canvas.drawArc rather than drawCircle